# Can I use curl to upload the content of a directory to Streamable.com

Tags: curl, cron

So my brother is making videos about their son, and he keep sending them to our Messenger family group chat, making the quality really poor.

The steps I would like to use are the next:

1. use dropbox/google drive to have a shared library on my 24/7 running ubuntu machine. (this I can solve)
2. have a cron job to watch this library for .mov files (I hope I can solve it)
3. use streamable.com's api to upload these videos with curl which is documented here.

https://streamable.com/documentation

curl https://api.streamable.com/upload \
  -u username:password \
  -F file=@myvideo.mp4

I've made a test with part 3 of this (uploading a video with curl) and got this weird long feedback in SSH:

> 405
>   Method Not Allowed
>
> ## Method Not Allowed
>
> The method
>   is not allowed for the requested URL.
>
> curl: (6) Could not resolve
>   host:  -u curl: (6) Could not resolve host: syluccy curl: (6) Could
>   not resolve host:  -F curl: (6) Could not resolve host: file=uccy
>   curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  -F
>
> Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page: It works
>          * {
>       margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
>       padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;   }
>
> body, html {
>       padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
>
> ```
> background-color: #D8DBE2;
>
> font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
> font-size: 11pt;
> text-align: center;   }
> ```
>
> div.main_page {
>       position: relative;
>       display: table;
>
> ```
> width: 800px;
>
> margin-bottom: 3px;
> margin-left: auto;
> margin-right: auto;
> padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
>
> border-width: 2px;
> border-color: #212738;
> border-style: solid;
>
> background-color: #FFFFFF;
>
> text-align: center;   }
> ```
>
> div.page_header {
>       height: 99px;
>       width: 100%;
>
> ```
> background-color: #F5F6F7;   }
> ```
>
> div.page_header span {
>       margin: 15px 0px 0px 50px;
>
> ```
> font-size: 180%;
> font-weight: bold;   }
> ```
>
> div.page_header img {
>       margin: 3px 0px 0px 40px;
>
> ```
> border: 0px 0px 0px;   }
> ```
>
> div.table_of_contents {
>       clear: left;
>
> ```
> min-width: 200px;
>
> margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
>
> background-color: #FFFFFF;
>
> text-align: left;   }
> ```
>
> div.table_of_contents_item {
>       clear: left;
>
> ```
> width: 100%;
>
> margin: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
>
> background-color: #FFFFFF;
>
> color: #000000;
> text-align: left;   }
> ```
>
> div.table_of_contents_item a {
>       margin: 6px 0px 0px 6px;   }
>
> div.content_section {
>       margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
>
> ```
> background-color: #FFFFFF;
>
> text-align: left;   }
> ```
>
> div.content_section_text {
>       padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px;
>
> ```
> color: #000000;
> font-size: 100%;   }
> ```
>
> div.content_section_text pre {
>       margin: 8px 0px 8px 0px;
>       padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
>
> ```
> border-width: 1px;
> border-style: dotted;
> border-color: #000000;
>
> background-color: #F5F6F7;
>
> font-style: italic;   }
> ```
>
> div.content_section_text p {
>       margin-bottom: 6px;   }
>
> div.content_section_text ul, div.content_section_text li {
>       padding: 4px 8px 4px 16px;   }
>
> div.section_header {
>       padding: 3px 6px 3px 6px;
>
> ```
> background-color: #8E9CB2;
>
> color: #FFFFFF;
> font-weight: bold;
> font-size: 112%;
> text-align: center;   }
> ```
>
> div.section_header_red {
>       background-color: #CD214F;   }
>
> div.section_header_grey {
>       background-color: #9F9386;   }
>
> .floating_element {
>       position: relative;
>       float: left;   }
>
> div.table_of_contents_item a,   div.content_section_text a {
>       text-decoration: none;
>       font-weight: bold;   }
>
> div.table_of_contents_item a:link,   div.table_of_contents_item
>   a:visited,   div.table_of_contents_item a:active {
>       color: #000000;   }
>
> div.table_of_contents_item a:hover {
>       background-color: #000000;
>
> ```
> color: #FFFFFF;   }
> ```
>
> div.content_section_text a:link,   div.content_section_text
>   a:visited,    div.content_section_text a:active {
>       background-color: #DCDFE6;
>
> ```
> color: #000000;   }
> ```
>
> div.content_section_text a:hover {
>       background-color: #000000;
>
> ```
> color: #DCDFE6;   }
> ```
>
> div.validator {   }
>             
>       
>         
>           
>           
>             Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page
>           
>          
>           
>             TABLE OF CONTENTS
>           </div>
>           
>             About</a>
>           </div>
>           
>             Changes</a>
>           </div>
>           
>             Scope</a>
>           </div>
>           
>             Config files</a>
>           </div>
>         </div>
>   -->
>
> ```
>     <div class="section_header section_header_red">
>       <div id="about"></div>
>       It works!
>     </div>
>     <div class="content_section_text">
>       <p>
>             This is the default welcome page used to test the correct 
>             operation of the Apache2 server after installation on Ubuntu systems.
>             It is based on the equivalent page on Debian, from which the Ubuntu Apache
>             packaging is derived.
>             If you can read this page, it means that the Apache HTTP server installed at
>             this site is working properly. You should <b>replace this file</b> (located at
>             <tt>/var/www/html/index.html</tt>) before continuing to operate your HTTP server.
>       </p>
>
>
>       <p>
>             If you are a normal user of this web site and don't know what this page is
>             about, this probably means that the site is currently unavailable due to
>             maintenance.
>             If the problem persists, please contact the site's administrator.
>       </p>
>
>     </div>
>     <div class="section_header">
>       <div id="changes"></div>
>             Configuration Overview
>     </div>
>     <div class="content_section_text">
>       <p>
>             Ubuntu's Apache2 default configuration is different from the
>             upstream default configuration, and split into several files optimized for
>             interaction with Ubuntu tools. The configuration system is
>             <b>fully documented in
>             /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz</b>. Refer to this for the full
>             documentation. Documentation for the web server itself can be
>             found by accessing the <a href="/manual">manual</a> if the <tt>apache2-doc</tt>
>             package was installed on this server.
>
>       </p>
>       <p>
>             The configuration layout for an Apache2 web server installation on Ubuntu systems is as follows:
>       </p>
>       <pre> /etc/apache2/ |-- apache2.conf |       `--  ports.conf |-- mods-enabled |       |-- *.load |       `-- *.conf |--
> ```
>
> conf-enabled |       `-- *.conf |-- sites-enabled |`-- *.conf
>
> apache2.conf is the main configuration
>                              file. It puts the pieces together by including all remaining configuration
>                              files when starting up the web server.
>
> ```
>                     <li>
>                        <tt>ports.conf</tt> is always included from the
>                        main configuration file. It is used to determine the listening ports for
>                        incoming connections, and this file can be customized anytime.
>                     </li>
>
>                     <li>
>                        Configuration files in the <tt>mods-enabled/</tt>,
>                        <tt>conf-enabled/</tt> and <tt>sites-enabled/</tt> directories contain
>                        particular configuration snippets which manage modules, global configuration
>                        fragments, or virtual host configurations, respectively.
>                     </li>
>
>                     <li>
>                        They are activated by symlinking available
>                        configuration files from their respective
>                        *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed
>                        by using our helpers
>                        <tt>
>                             <a href="http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=a2enmod">a2enmod</a>,
>                             <a href="http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=a2dismod">a2dismod</a>,
>                        </tt>
>                        <tt>
>                             <a href="http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=a2ensite">a2ensite</a>,
>                             <a href="http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=a2dissite">a2dissite</a>,
>                         </tt>
>                             and
>                        <tt>
>                             <a href="http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=a2enconf">a2enconf</a>,
>                             <a href="http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=a2disconf">a2disconf</a>
>                        </tt>. See their respective man pages for detailed information.
>                     </li>
>
>                     <li>
>                        The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of
>                        environment variables, in the default configuration, apache2 needs to be
>                        started/stopped with <tt>/etc/init.d/apache2</tt> or <tt>apache2ctl</tt>.
>                        <b>Calling <tt>/usr/bin/apache2</tt> directly will not work</b> with the
>                        default configuration.
>                     </li>
>       </ul>
>     </div>
>
>     <div class="section_header">
>         <div id="docroot"></div>
>             Document Roots
>     </div>
>
>     <div class="content_section_text">
>         <p>
>             By default, Ubuntu does not allow access through the web browser to
>             <em>any</em> file apart of those located in <tt>/var/www</tt>,
>             <a href="http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_userdir.html">public_html</a>
>             directories (when enabled) and <tt>/usr/share</tt> (for web
>             applications). If your site is using a web document root
>             located elsewhere (such as in <tt>/srv</tt>) you may need to whitelist your
>             document root directory in <tt>/etc/apache2/apache2.conf</tt>.
>         </p>
>         <p>
>             The default Ubuntu document root is <tt>/var/www/html</tt>. You
>             can make your own virtual hosts under /var/www. This is different
>             to previous releases which provides better security out of the box.
>         </p>
>     </div>
>
>     <div class="section_header">
>       <div id="bugs"></div>
>             Reporting Problems
>     </div>
>     <div class="content_section_text">
>       <p>
>             Please use the <tt>ubuntu-bug</tt> tool to report bugs in the
>             Apache2 package with Ubuntu. However, check <a
>             href="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2">existing
>             bug reports</a> before reporting a new bug.
>       </p>
>       <p>
>             Please report bugs specific to modules (such as PHP and others)
>             to respective packages, not to the web server itself.
>       </p>
>     </div>
>
>
>
>
>   </div>
> </div>
> <div class="validator">
> </div>   </body> </html>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You are using backslash incorrectly, in your case `\` is used for line continuation :

```
curl https://api.streamable.com/upload -u username:password -F file=@myvideo.mp4
```

Or :

```
curl https://api.streamable.com/upload \
  -u username:password \
  -F file=@myvideo.mp4
```

From [man bash](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Escape-Character) :

> A non-quoted backslash ‘\’ is the Bash escape character. It preserves
>   the literal value of the next character that follows, with the
>   exception of newline. If a \newline pair appears, and the backslash
>   itself is not quoted, the \newline is treated as a line continuation
>   (that is, it is removed from the input stream and effectively
>   ignored).